# Numbers with has the first digit $2$

Tags: probability

What is the probability that choose a number from N, it has the first digit $2$?

I tried to find the numbers which has the first digit $2$ and has $N$ digits. If a obtain the number of these, noted $A$, then probability is $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{A}{n}$?

Comment: It depends upon your distribution, i.e., the probability of choosing each number.  You need to give us more information.

Comment: You might find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law of interest.

Comment: You cannot pick a natural number randomly. We can say the density of the numbers that start with $2$ in the naturals is $\frac19$, but that's something else entirely than "choosing a number"

Comment: For any $A\in\mathbb R$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{A}{n}=0$, but as it's quite unclear how you're picking numbers, I guess $0$ might be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: No, because A depends of n

Answer (score 0):

Consider the 9 whole numbers from 1 to 9 - how many of those 9 numbers start with 2?

Now consider the 90 whole numbers from 10 to 99 - how many of those 90 numbers start with 2 ?

Now consider the 900 whole numbers from 100 to 999 - how many of those 900 numbers start with 2 ?

Continue the pattern ...

(but, as pointed out above, you will have to make some assumption about the probability of choosing each number).

Comment: Well this method is just plain incorrect. Take the numbers $1,2$; how many begin with $2$? Now take $1,2,\cdots,28,29$, how many of those start with $2$? What about $1,2,\cdots,298,299$? Yup, a little more than half of all the numbers start with a $2$.

Comment: @vrugtehagel.  Don't you mean a little over a third?  And 3-29, and 30- 299

Comment: Yeah a little over a third, my mistake. My point still stands though.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that 'number' here means positive integers with not more than $M$ digits.

Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers with not more than $M$ digits.

Let $S_n$ be the set of all positive integers with the first digit $n$.

$$S=S_1\cup S_2\cup \cdots\cup S_9$$

and $|S_1|=|S_2|=|S_3|=\dots=|S_9|$.

The probability should be $\displaystyle \frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: It's not possible to select a positive integer with all being equally likely.

Comment: @Henrik Actually I also wonder how to do that.  My "answer" depends on how to interpret the question. If it is about choosing a number of not more than a certain number of digits, then I think it is OK. But for the whole $\mathbb{Z}^+$, I am not sure whether it is possible to have the equally likely assumption.

Comment: Why the distribution is uniformly?

Comment: @Petrisor I don't know how we can randomly choose a number from infinitely many numbers.  I am not sure whether it is possible.  I will edit my answer to cover only numbers of not more than a certain number of digits. You may unaccept it and see whether somebody can give a better one.

Comment: This question is similar with: probability that choose a number from N , it is  divisible by 5. In this case, the probability is 1/5

Comment: Because the probability is $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{card(A)}{n}$, when A is the set of numbers divisible by 5 from the set {1,2,...n}